# How to pass a variable to Process Task Editor in SSDT?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

How to pass a variable to Process Task Editor in SSDT?

At present, I have hard coded the Executable folder path in the Property Name : Executable.

How to pass the folder path value dynamically through a variable for "Execute Process Task"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highlight the Execute Process Task and go to the properties window (press `F4`).  Go the `Expressions` field, click on the ellipsis, and go to the `Executable` Property.  Here you can add a variable for the `Executable` property.  If this value is set during package execution, then `DelayValidation` will need to be set to `True` on the Execute Process Task.

Comment: I am fetching the folder path value from the database configuration. Value is picked from Execute SQL Task and assigned to the SSIS Variable : ZipFilePath. However, it is throwing an exception..Attached the screenshot

Comment: Error at Execute Process Task : The executable is not specified.

Comment: If the variable you're using is currently empty but will be set at run-time, set DelayValidation to True on the Execute Process Task.

Comment: Good to hear, I updated my answer to include this as well.